# What's wrong with my importing path & clicking to open file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just started a new job, and therefore a new setup. It's not all that different but for some reason I am having 2 problems related to what the import path shows, and clicking on files/components to open the file do not work.

Could this be because of the `jsconfig` file?:

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "checkJs": false,
        "target": "es2017",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
          "test-utils": ["../jest.config.js"]
        }
      },
      "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
    }
```

---

**ISSUE 1**

- My import paths sometimes show relative path, sometimes not. Example `Provider` correctly imports from `node_modules`, but the `Checkbox` does not:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux'; // YES
    import { Checkbox } from '../../../node_modules/antd/lib/index'; // NO

    export default function test() {
      return (
        <Provider>
          <Checkbox />
        </Provider>
      );
    }
```

So in VSCode, i have checked my settings **JavaScript › Preferences: Import Module Specifier**. It is currently set to `auto`. If I change it to `relative`, no changes are visible. If I change it to `non-relative`, the Checkbox import changes to:

`import { Checkbox } from '../node_modules/antd/lib/index';` but this is still not what I would expect for a node_module import.

If I delete the JSConfig, then the import { Checkbox } behavior looks correct. However I am apparently the only one with this issue on my team.

**ISSUE 2**

- Sometimes clicking on a component to open a file by pressing `Command key (⌘) + Click` does not open the file, sometimes it does.

```
    import StatusKey from '../../components/StatusKey'; // (⌘) + Click does not work
    import { columns } from './tableColumns';  // (⌘) + Click works
```

GIF: http://recordit.co/GKZfRa7emo

However, if I change the StatusKey import to `import StatusKey from 'components/StatusKey/index';` then it works.

If I delete the JSConfig, then the click on Status key works with original import.

---

I appreciate the insight

Comment: And if you use `import { Checkbox } from 'antd/lib/index';` if antd is a node-module

Comment: It should just be import { Checkbox } from 'antd'

Comment: then why do you have this odd directory, if this works for your team mates there is something wrong on there machines too

Comment: that is what I am hoping for also...

Comment: But is the JSConfig file setup correctly?

Comment: I tried `antd` with the VSC react tutorial and used `import { Checkbox } from 'antd';` in `App.js` => this works. No `jsconfig.json`. Remove/Rename `jsconfig.json` and se if that works for you too, if so `jsconfig.json` has an error. `jsconfig.json` is only needed for intellisense and limiting the files it scans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the jsconfig needs to have `"module": "commonjs",` as part of the compilerOptions